# Difference when printing PDF file to different printers

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm generating PDF files and they look OK in Acrobat Reader. However, when I try to print documents to different printers, selecting the same "Fit To Page" scaling option, the results are a bit different.

One printer leaves a bit different page margins and space between characters.

Is it generally possible to achieve exactly the same looking printouts on different printers with the same scaling options? If yes, is there some sort of check-list for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can never guarantee the output from device to device.  This is because the printer interpret what you send it, and often uses built-in fonts and other resources that might be slightly different from manufacturer to manufacturer.  You could do the following to help:

- Embed all fonts into the PDF (including system fonts)
- Force the printer driver to download all fonts and not use the ones internal on the device
- Whenever possible, don't scale, send it down in the native size.  This might mean that you have to make the output small enough to fit in the print window of a wide range of printers

The other thing to keep in mind is that when printing PDF files, if you use Postscript, there is a high likelihood that Acrobat Reader will do the PDF to PS conversion and pass it through the driver.  You probably see an option in the print driver relating to this.  Leaving it on pass-through should give you more consistent results.

There is also an option in Acrobat Reader to "print as image".  This will slow printing dramatically but could assist.

If you have an application that is sending this file to print keep in mind that many newer printers support native PDF printing.  This means you can simply fire the PDF at the device itself and not have to view or print it from Acrobat.  In this case you are doing one less conversion / interpretation, so it could help.